# hashdeep with sha1 and sha1sum create different results

Tags: security, hash

I computed a sha1 hash of the file '/etc/mtab' with hashdeep on Ubuntu 16.04. Then I computed a sha1 hash of the same file with sha1sum. And I got a different hash!

When computing hashes for other files, both programs seem to create the same hash. Finally, I copied the file to another computer and ran the two programs there. On the second computer they both computed the same hash that was computed on the first computer by sha1sum. At last, I checked the file '/etc/mtab' on the second computer, not the copied one, with hashdeep and sha1sum and I also got different results again.

The same goes for sha256 when using hashdeep and sha256sum.

I am calling `hashdeep -c sha256 /etc/mtab` and `sha256sum /etc/mtab`

Does anyone know how this can happen? Is there a caching implementation for hashdeep, thus older hashes are stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran that on my system and it went well these were my results:

Ran: `hashdeep -c sha256 Xwrapper.config`

```
%%%% HASHDEEP-1.0
%%%% size,sha256,filename
## Invoked from: /home/george/Documents/askubuntu
## $ hashdeep -c sha256 Xwrapper.config
## 
630,c53eb030a8f9a2f7c08dd04e3611c9470f840d90d1261ef3e6643b1d1aff8608,/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/Xwrapper.config
```

Ran: `sha256sum Xwrapper.config`

```
c53eb030a8f9a2f7c08dd04e3611c9470f840d90d1261ef3e6643b1d1aff8608  Xwrapper.config
```

Ok let explain as best as I can, after checking several things I see some thing about how `hashdeep` and `sha256sum` see `symbolic links`. When I do `stat /etc/mtab` I see the size is `19`, but when I run ( with the `l`, link option):

```
 hashdeep -o l /etc/mtab
```

It returns nothing but if I do:

```
 hashdeep -o f /atc/mtab
```

It returns the hash below but note that the size is `0` different from what `stat /ec/mtab` gave earlier:

```
 %%%% HASHDEEP-1.0
 %%%% size,md5,sha256,filename
 ## Invoked from: /etc
 ## $ hashdeep -o lf /etc/mtab
 ## 0,d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e,e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855,/etc/mtab
```

It sees the file as **regular file** since I used the `f` option and hence reports or calculates the `sha256` from an empty file, whereas the `sha256sum` sees it as a `symbolic link` and of size `19`. So simply put when the file is a regular file it gives similar results but not so when a `link`.

Note that that file is a link to `proc/self/mounts` which `hashdeep` still sees  as `0` in size but is seen by `stat` as `19` size, so `hashdeep` does follow that link but seems not to be able to read the contents or see the contents of that file. It does however see the `/etc/vtrgb` as a non-empty file, so I guess `/etc/mtab` link to `/proc/self/mounts` matters.

It even gets more interesting and confirms my suspicion about `/etc/mtab` link to `/proc/self/mounts` as I ran this on another link `hashdeep /etc/vtrgb`:

```
%%%% HASHDEEP-1.0
%%%% size,md5,sha256,filename
## Invoked from: /etc
## $ hashdeep /etc/vtrgb
## 158,1fb3c13c4fcfa8cc4131aba905df559e,684cd905549f78e025870dd5c8a3835e49f79f2bb08952eb7424537f6df5fa13,/etc/vtrgb
```

As you will note the **size** is not **zero** as was the case with `/etc/mtab`, and running:

```
 sha256sum /etc/vtrgb
```

Returns the same `checksum`:

```
 684cd905549f78e025870dd5c8a3835e49f79f2bb08952eb7424537f6df5fa13  /etc/vtrgb
```

Further investigation shows that `hashdeep` returns the same `hash`

```
0,d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e,e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

for all files and directory in `/proc/` which is actually a `pseudo filesystem` hence their information is stored in memory not on disk. Whereas `sha256sum` does not but returns different `checksum` for these same files.

Comment: Could you run it on '/etc/mtab', too?